# Helm - how to do a .Files.Get for a file inside a library?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have defined a library that has the following structure:

```
helm-libs/
- files
    - script.lua
- templates
    - _hello.yaml
- Chart.yaml
```

in the hello.yaml, I include the file by using this snippet:

```
{{ $.Files.Get "files/script.lua" | nindent 10 }}
```

Now when I use this library inside an application chart, I do a `helm dependency update`, which brings in the library into that application's charts folder.

When I install the helm chart, I don't see the file's contents coming into the template.

So my question is how can I do a files.get on a file that's inside a library?